# iOS Image in navigation Item titleview

Tags: ios, navigationbar, titleview

I want to add an image in my navigation bar. To do this, i wrote that :

```
        self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
```

It's running, but the only problem is the image seems to be blurred. 
When i look it on photoshop or other software, the image is perfect.

The size of this image is : 120 x 30px.

Someone to help me ? Thx

Comment: You want to add image in navigation bar or navigation item title?

Comment: In the navigationitem.titleview, and so in the navigation bar :)

Comment: Navigation bar is different from navigation item

Comment: I don't understand. The navigation item is display in a navigation bar, no ?

Comment: Navigation bar contains back button, title, accessory buttons, etc etc..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please, print self.navigationItem.titleView.frame after your viewDidAppear.

Seems to be, that in some case your titleView is placed with half-pixeled origin.x, or origin.y.

Try to play with:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:<#(CGFloat)#> forBarMetrics:<#(UIBarMetrics)#>]
```

Try to set different values to the first param and observe the result.

Comment: Sorry, i solved the problem, i needed to add an other image with "@2x" for the retina screen. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the navigation and status bar background only in iOS7. For this, you can use

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The size should be **320*64 px**

and to change the Navigation Bar title

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]];
```

Comment: Sorry, i solved the problem, i needed to add an other image with "@2x" for the retina screen. Thx for your help.